# 2D Normal PDF with ggplot and R

Tags: r, ggplot2, contour, probability-density

I'm trying to make a contour/image plot using ggplot but with no success til now.

Consider the following piece of code in R that creates a matrix `z` with the PDF of a bivariate normal:

```
require(mvtnorm)
x1 = seq(-3, 3, length.out=200)
x2 = seq(-3, 3, length.out=200)
z = matrix(0, length(x1), length(x2))
for (i in 1:length(x1)) {
    a = x1
    b = x2[i]
    z[,i] = dmvnorm(cbind(a,b))
}
image(x1,x2,z)
```

[image: 2D normal pdf image plot]

Is it possible to plot the matrix `z` using ggplot?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# reshape the data
require(reshape2)
dat <- melt(z)

# use geom_raster to mimic image

gg <- ggplot(dat, aes(x=Var2, y=Var1, fill=value))
gg <- gg + labs(x="", y="")
gg <- gg + geom_raster()
gg <- gg + coord_equal()
gg <- gg + scale_fill_gradient(low="red", high="yellow")
gg <- gg + scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
gg <- gg + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0))
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg
```

[image]

You can change the axis labels pretty easily if you need to.

Comment: + 1 Just add this step to your answer: `dat$Var1 <- x1`,
`dat$Var2 <- rep(x2, each=200)` then the x and y axis are going to be correct.